# What does the <Class> notation mean?

Tags: c#

What is the meaning of `<>` here:

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build()
```

`Startup` is a class but I have only come across <> in enumerable types like lists etc. Please can someone refer to the C# topic I need to look up as googling C# <> produces garbage.

Comment: It is a generic parameter to the `UseStartup<T>` method.

Answer (score 1):

It is a C# generic. It means that any type can go there as needed, and the same operation will be done on the object. This is often used in C# collections, because the collections are just a way to store the data without caring for what's inside.

Another way to achieve the same effect is called *boxing*, which is when a type is cast to its base `Object` type. However, using items that are boxed requires casting them back into their original datatype, which can cause issues if an unexpected type shows up. On the other hand, creating a generic method with `<T>` ensures that the operation is performed on a certain type at runtime.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/ for more information.